# OPmac mnote with hyperlink bug?

Tags: plain-tex, opmac

When typesetting the following (using pdfTeX or luaTeX) the rightmost bracket of the cross reference in the marginal note is colored as if part of the hyperlink (though not actually part of the link), which I believe it should not be.  The left bracket is black and not part of the link:

```
\input opmac

% Enable hyperlinks
\hyperlinks\Red\Red

\newcount\somecounter \somecounter 1

\label[test]\wlabel{T.\the\somecounter} This is a test

More Text and now we put a cross reference in a marginal note: \mnote{[\ref[test]]}

\bye
```

[image: screenshot]

So far I've only seen this behaviour in marginal notes via \mnote.

Comment: It seems that everything after `\ref[...]` in the `\mnote` is considered part of the link. A bug, undoubtedly. But the text after `T.1` is not part of the link.

Comment: @egreg, as you and Heiko both noticed, the "link" part wasn't affected, just the colour of text after it.  I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is dicussed in [OPmac trick 0037](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks.html#colmnote) from March 2014. I'll try to transtate it:

If you need to switch the colors in paragraph with usage of `\mnote`s, probably color puzzlement occurs. The `\mnote` is processed by macros in its occurrence but it is inserted after current paragraph line by `\vadjust` primitive.
The `\mnote` have the color as the current line at its end. The version OPmac Mar2014 or latter solves the problem by possibility to add the color by `\mnotehook`. This color has "global" validity "locally" in each `\mnote` and it doesn't affect the color of lines in the main paragraph.  For example you need to have all `\mnote`s blue:

```
\def\mnotehook{\noindent\Blue}
```

The `\noindent` is needed here becuase the color mark in vertical mode breaks the right placement of the `\mnote` text.

Why OPmac doesn't declare `\def\mnotehook{\noindent\Black}` by default? Because the default behavior is to inherit the color from the current text of main paragraph for `\mnote`s.

More colors can be in the `\mnote` text (in groups declared by `\localcolor`, for example). If the `\localcolor` isn't used here, the color ends at the end of the `\mnote` text.

Comment: @acarlow Thank you for this report. I've added the following sentence to the mentioned OPmac trick: Warning: If the color isn't initialized by `\mnotehook` or at the beginning of the `\mnote` text then the "local colorstack" in `\mnote` text doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and updating the "trick" documentation.  Unfortunately, the only way I can read the tricks is with the Google translator and often the meaning doesn't translate well or at all.  Hopefully this exchange will offer English speakers another resource.

Comment: As an aside, there still seems to be a problem with the implementation if the color of text after the link is supposed to be the same as the color of the paragraph to which the mnote is attached, no?

Comment: @acarlow Yes, the problem is that there is an asynchronous color processing: the macro expansion is processed at different time than the color marks are stored in PDF via `\vadjust`. Macros in `\mnote` are unable to know the current color in the parahraph (exactly at the end of the current line of the paragraph). Thus the base mnote color is unknown by macros. I'm considering to change the behavior of `\restorecolor` to base mnote color from the current "do nothing" to "return to Black". Both are not 100% right. If user needs color manipulation in mnotes he/she has to set colors explicitly.

Comment: I understand.  In my opinion, simply defaulting `\mnote`s to black makes the most sense.  If I hadn't known anything about this issue, I wouldn't have been surprised that `\mnote`s defaulted to black instead of the color of the `\mnote`'s source paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

`\mnote` clears the color, in `\mnoteC`:

```
\def\currcolork{}
\def\currcolorK{}
```

Then the link sets the color `\Red` inside a group:

```
{\localcolor \Red}
```

`\localcolor` restores the color after the group via `\restorecolor`. But because the current color at the start of `\mnote` is empty, nothing is restored and the color remains red.

Workaround:

```
\mnote{[\Black\ref[test]]}
```

Then the color can be restored after the link to black.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out that it was just the colour and not the actual hyperlink that was affected (I mistakenly thought it was the link).  Also, the workaround works perfect.

Comment: @wipet has given more specifics about the implementation below.  Either a global \mnotehook or a local color color change in the \mnote itself as shown by Heiko can be used to fix the issue.